# Conflict in using Netfix hystrix and Archaius

Tags: hystrix, netflix, netflix-archaius

I am getting below error while using hystrix and archaius together. Independently both are working perfectly fine.

> **IllegalStateException("A non-default configuration is already installed");**

Please let me know if anyone has faced similar issue.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your project and exception

Comment: I have developed a simple application micro services based. One of the micro services is using hystrix where I am unable to configure archaius and its causing IllegalStateException in ConfigurationManager class of archaius jar. Hystrix internally is using archaius so I am not able to call ConfigurationManager.install() method.

Comment: you have to show the code snippets, how you have configured, and complete exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved by changing the dependency from

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.archaius</groupId>
        <artifactId>archaius-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

to this

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-archaius</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and no code required for the scheduler configuration. Everyting is managed by spring-cloud-starter-archaius.